# Why this strategy does not work on other pairs?

Tags: pine-script

This code cannot be compiled or used in other pairs, it only works in BTC!!!

**What should I do if I want to use it in other pairs?**

( **when I use this strategy on other pairs,** I see a alarm notification in front of the indicator. If you hover your mouse pointer over this warning sign, **you will notice a footnote that warns you that this indicator is not working properly** and the information is not processed properly. (**please look at to the second picture**) ibb.co/zmCCDrm )

**And how do I write a warning for that?**

```
//@version=2
//                     simple cross of daily candle close
//
strategy("DailyCandleCross", shorttitle="DCC", overlay=true, calc_on_order_fills= true, calc_on_every_tick=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=75, pyramiding=0)
A=security(tickerid, 'D', close)
B=security(tickerid, 'D', close[1])
C=A>B
if(C)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if(not C)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code to fix the cross calculation:
This code will print a "Long" label whenever the new daily candle close, cross over the previous daily candle close (That means it will generate a lot of labels!):

```
//@version=4
//                     simple cross of daily candle close
//
study("DailyCandleCross", shorttitle="DCC", overlay=true)
A=security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)
longCondition = crossover(A , A[1])
shortCondition = crossunder(A , A[1])
if(longCondition)
    label.new(bar_index, low , "Long" ,style = label.style_label_up , color= color.green , textcolor= color.white)
if(shortCondition)
    label.new(bar_index, high , "Short" , color = color.red , textcolor= color.white)
```

Use the "crossover" function to check if a series crossed the other series.
To be honest I don't know if I understood your goal clearly or not and I don't know what are you trying to achieve with this either.

Comment: Hi Behnam, thanks, but why the results are different? (please look at to the picture)     https://ibb.co/TbmRntQ

Comment: and about the errors: when I use this strategy on other pairs like ETH and NEO I see a alarm notification in front of the indicator. If you hover your mouse pointer over this warning sign, you will notice a footnote that warns you that this indicator is not working properly and the information is not processed properly. (please look at to the second picture)  https://ibb.co/zmCCDrm

Comment: @Armin There are several reasons for this. first: your strategy is miscalculating the cross and I just converted it to study, and I left the logic as is. Also, there is a limit of 50 drawings per indicator so only the last 50 bars are drawing the labels. I updated the answer to fix the cross calculation.

Comment: I think we lost some thing in your code, because as you can see the results are different, what do you think about this? (please look at to the picture) https://ibb.co/Y3Sb8zb

Comment: Yes, the result must be different. because: 1- if you don't close an open position, new signals will not be generated unless the position closes itself with a short signal or you set pyramiding to bigger than 1. So your code is generating fewer signals than mine. 2- I used the "crossover" function to calculate the daily candle cross, which I believe is the correct way. but your code is generating a long signal every time the daily candle is higher than a previous daily candle (since you said that you want a candle "cross" I think you don't want that to happen because that is not a "cross")

Comment: If you believe that my code is incorrect please provide more information about your problem and your use case scenario maybe we could help you more accurately.

Comment: My code provides a better entry and exit area and, as you said, gives a long signal, so we do not need to close and open our position many times, if the trend wave changes, it will give us signals every day, my problem was only two things, I cannot use it in other pairs + I wanted to convert it to study mode, because this is a strategy and I cannot define the warning on it. It would be great if you could help me solve these two problems and reach the same output as the strategy indicator output, I posted in the first post.

Comment: can you please tell me how I can write alert on my own code? I think maybe it can be better if we don't change the code and just write a alert on it, thank you very much in advance. :)